# relation between $u,\partial u / \partial n$ and $\Delta u$

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

Let $\Omega$ be a simple domain, for example a square, and $u$ be an uknown function.

If the values of $u$ and $\partial u/ \partial n(=\nabla u.n)$ be known on $\partial \Omega$, is there any way to find $\Delta u$ on $\partial \Omega$.Here $n$ is unit outward normal vector.

It got a lot of time of me, but I could not find anything about it. Is it possible?

Comment: What is $u$ and what is $\partial/\partial n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not.

Take for example $\Omega=D$, the unit  disk. Assume that $u=u(r)$. Then 
$u\mid_{\partial\Omega}=u(1)$, $\partial_\nu u\mid_{\partial\Omega}=u'(1)$ and $\Delta u\mid_{\partial\Omega}=u''(1)+u'(1)$.

Apparently, $u$ can not be determined from $u(1)$, $u'(1)$ and $u''(1)$.